# Error 1004 while setting validations via vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'am setting validations based on list in text format on a cell via vba using XL365. Lists are quite long but this never caused an issue (for months) - and did not on Excel2013 on a different PC this morning.

It returns a 1004 error now.

Have set up my PC from scratch last week. Did not try the code again before today. Observed some updates being installed today as well.

The lists used for validation did not change. They have been very very long ever since.

(me.vars.rng is just a simple Xl range defined in a variable container)

```
Public Sub subSetValidationListOnRng(strValidationList As String)
    With Me.Vars.Rng
        On Error Resume Next
        .Validation.Delete
        If Len(strValidationList) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        .Validation.Delete
        On Error Resume Next
        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=strValidationList
        .Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
        .Validation.InCellDropdown = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What line returns the error?  How long are the lists?  What error are you trying to avoid with your `On Error Resume Next` statements?

Comment: The list is somewhat 650 characters long and has around 30 items.

Comment: & yes I am trying to avoid with resume next - but it is somewhat hard to sell user-experience-wise ... (no selection & you have to copy manually ...). Especially, as it has been working in the past. (Same length of the list. No changes on that side)

Comment: You have chosen not to share information about the which line returns the error.  And handling errors, rather than ignoring them, should give you the level of control you require without upsetting user experience. Your error probably means there is a problem with the way you are setting up the conditional format object.  (I had found that with very long lists, there was a problem with `.xlsm` not present with `.xlsb` files, but those lists were > 1000 words, and gave a different error.

Comment: The line returning the error is the one with .validation.add.

Comment: (Sorry for not deleting the on error line causing confusion)

Comment: ... have introduced the "resume next" in order to continue working.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with a shorter list and a ***hard-coded*** `Me.Vars.Rng`.  Suggests your code is OK.

Comment: A little testing suggests the length of a validation list string is limited to 255 characters.  I suggest you set up your validation list as a range, rather than a string.